# How can I tell if my hourly cron job has run?

Tags: server, scripts, cron

I have created a file called `ntpdate` in `/etc/cron.hourly`

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/ntpdate-debian
date > /tmp/william_tmp
date > /william_tmp
date > ~/william_tmp
echo test
```

I also did Chmod 755 to this file.

However, I can't tell if the file has run or not!

The file is not created in any of the 3 directories.

If I manually run `cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly` then the files are created and I get the echo.

Can anyone recommend (ideally step by step!) instructions to test that it is working?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One major pitfall to cron is cron runs in an extremely limited shell environment, as a result a lot of variables aren't exported in to the environment, mainly $PATH. Make sure you use all absolute paths to executable, including common functions like `echo`, `uptime`, `date`, etc all need to use full paths (`/bin/echo`, `/bin/date`, `/usr/bin/uptime`). To determine the path to an executable, you can use the `which` command like so: `which echo` - this will show you the full path to that tool.

Comment: As discussed in chat, thanks for this and I really hope it will help someone else... Whilst I did the fall path to ntpdate, I am so used to Windows and echo/date being just "built in", I just didn't think I would need full path... learning a lot more about Linux and it makes perfect sense!

Comment: Does this mean that any envirnment variable included in `.bash_profile` does not get carried over to the job being executed using cron?

Answer (score 43):

You should look in your `/var/log/syslog` log file. If a cron has run, it would have a line like:

```
Jun 11 19:09:01 penguin CRON[17376]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Jun 11 19:17:01 penguin CRON[17799]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

For troubleshooting tips, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Troubleshooting_and_Common_Problems

Comment: There isn't anything in Syslog and I can't see any reason why it would fail from that link :(

Comment: If there are no entries in syslog (`grep -i cron /var/log/syslog /var/log/syslog.1`), start checking whether the cron daemon is running: `ps uww -C cron` should contain a line with a process.

Comment: Sorry for being misleading, there are entires for Cron in the syslog, just nothing relating to this command... I know some jobs get run as every hour, I get a new mail alert... AFAIK, the ones that are working are from crontab, there is nothing in cron.hourly which is what I am trying to get working

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the first line of your script (the interpreter) to:

`#!/bin/bash`

I've also had problems in the past, with environment variables and PATH issues. After changing the interpreter to `bash` my issues were gone.

Answer (score 2):

Given I've added the `clearme.sh` script in `/etc/cron.hourly/`

Just filter CRON tasks in **terminal** with the powerful **egrep** and **awk**:

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | egrep clearme | awk "{ print $1 }" > ~/Desktop/cronlog.txt
```

The output will look like:

```
Jan 14 15:20:01 markets-dev CRON[10089]: (dminca) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/clearme.sh)
Jan 14 15:40:01 markets-dev CRON[18042]: (dminca) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/clearme.sh)
Jan 14 16:00:01 markets-dev CRON[22817]: (dminca) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/clearme.sh)
Jan 14 16:20:01 markets-dev CRON[28183]: (dminca) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/clearme.sh)
Jan 14 16:40:01 markets-dev CRON[411]: (dminca) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/clearme.sh)
Jan 14 17:00:01 markets-dev CRON[5442]: (dminca) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/clearme.sh)
Jan 14 17:20:01 markets-dev CRON[11935]: (dminca) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/clearme.sh)
```

To explain everything step-by-step:

1. *cat /var/log/syslog* - print me the System log
2. *egrep clearme* - but only select rows that contain the text **clearme**
3. *awk "{ print $1 }"* - print me that row that contains the text **clearme**
4. *> ~/Desktop/cronlog.txt* - output the results in the file **cronlog.txt** located on the **Desktop** directory.

The 4th step is optional. It will just print results in the terminal instead of the file.