# Crontab script entry not working

Tags: scripts, cron

beginner here.
I have a script called

```
updateTf2.sh
```

It's contents

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/srcds stop
./steamcmd/sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir ./tf2 +app_update 232250 +quit
/etc/init.d/srcds start
```

Located here

```
~/home/user/updateTf2.sh
```

If I run ./updateTf2.sh from terminal it asks for a password, I type it in, and the script runs successfully.

When I put it in sudo crontab -e like this

```
10 9 * * * /home/user/updateTf2.sh
```

It doesn't run.

What am I doing wrong? I've seen simular tickets about this topic on here but have not seen a clear answer.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The commands executed by cron don't have a terminal connection, so they cannot interactively ask for user responses. If the desired remote server asks for a password with anonymous login you will have to use another mechanism to authenticate the program `steamcmd.sh`, like configuring it to use some Steam AppID as depicted in [How to install and use SteamCMD](https://danielgibbs.co.uk/2014/02/steamcmd/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very very common mistake. You need to use the full path in scripts (rather then the relative path).

chron runs with sh using minimal environmental variables.

Comment: So I should change my script to this #!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/srcds stop
/home/user/steamcmd/sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/user/tf2 +app_update 232250 +quit
/etc/init.d/srcds start

Comment: Yes give it a try with the full path

Comment: I changed it but not sure if it works. Is there a way to output to the screen so I know that it ran or not? Examples would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `grep updateTf2.sh /var/log/syslog` , see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/149504/how-can-i-tell-if-my-hourly-cron-job-has-run